# Cannot create array of substrings split by separator

Tags: arrays, c, string, substring

I am trying to split a string of multiple words separated by blank spaces into an array of substrings.

There exists a problem preventing the code to work properly. It successfully finds the breakpoints' indexes but it does not print the array of separated elements correctly.

The code is supposed to create an array containing the names given in the string.

Why is the code not running as desired?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string [] = " Joe James John Maria Micheal";
    int breakPoints[5];
    char ch = ' ';
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        if (string[i] == ch) {
            breakPoints[counter] = i;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", breakPoints[i]);
    }

    char *array[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        strncpy(array[i], string + breakPoints[i], breakPoints[i + 1] - breakPoints[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%s ", array[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory to `array[5]` `char` pointers before copying string to them.

Comment: Alternatively, you can modify the string by overwriting each "breakpoint" with the character `'\0'`.  Then you can store pointers into the original string instead of copying words out.  This is essentially how `strtok` works.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the value of `array[i]`, you have to allocate memory for it. In addition to that, there was an offset error in the `count` of characters for each token, so it was including a whitespace in the end. Here is your source code with such edits (and a few more small style changes).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SEP ' '

int main(void)
{
    char* string = " Joe James John Maria Micheal";
    int lenght = strlen(string);

    int counter = 0;
    int breakpoints[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        if (string[i] == SEP)
            breakpoints[counter++] = i;

    printf("\nBreakpoints: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d ", breakpoints[i]);

    char* array[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int start = breakpoints[i] + 1;
        int count = breakpoints[i + 1] - breakpoints[i] - 1;

        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * count + 1);
        strncpy(array[i], &string[start], count);
        array[i][count] = '\0';
    }

    printf("\nTokens: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("'%s' ", array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
        array[i] = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In time, if you intend to use this as part of another piece of code, notice that it dynamically allocates memory for each element of `array`, make the changes to properly handle it.

Comment: I highly suggest freeing the memory allocation in the answer, as it may help reader to not accidentally cause a memory leak

Comment: Suggestion accepted, but I've changed it to the same loop.

Comment: Also, fixed missing null character terminator on each array element and the possible dangling pointer, since we are now freeing the allocated memory!

Answer (score 0):

> *Why is the code not running as desired?*

This

```
char *array[5];
```

is array of `5` character pointers. In the `for` loop you are copying strings to unallocated pointers which is undefined behaviour.

Even if you allocate memory to the `array` pointers, your program output will not be as desired because of following reasons:

**Reason no. 1**:
Here

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
```

you are copying only `4` substrings but the input strings has `5` substrings separated by a space (`' '`) characters. The output will miss the last substring.

**Reason no. 2**:
The starting offset, while copying in `strncpy`, includes the substrings preceding space as the `breakPoints` array keep the information about the location of space in the given input string.

The way you wrote the code, it becomes necessary for the input string to have a blank space (separator) as first character because while copying the substring, you are copying the characters from current processing `breakpoints` array element to next `breakpoints` element. If there is no blank space (separator) at the start of string, the first element of `breakpoints` array will be the position of first blank space which is after the first word of given string.

You don't need to have another array to keep the information about the spaces (separator) in the given input string. You can make use of [strpbrk()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) to find out the next separator and copy the substring from current position to next separator position provided the current position is pointing at start of a word in the given string.

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 100

char * alloc_str (const char * start, const char * end) {
    if (!start || !end || (start >= end)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char * tmp = malloc (end - start + 1);
    if (tmp) {
        strncpy (tmp, start, end - start);
        tmp[end - start] = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return tmp;
}

void dealloc_str (char ** p_substr) {
    if (p_substr) {
        for (int i = 0; p_substr[i]; ++i) {
            free (p_substr[i]);
            p_substr[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {
    char string[] = " Joe James John Maria Micheal";
    char * p_substr[MAX_WORDS + 1] = {0};
    char * p_curr = string;
    const char * sep = " ";
    unsigned int word_cnt = 0;

    while (p_curr && *p_curr) {
        char * p_next;

        // skip separator
        p_curr += strspn(p_curr, sep);

        p_next = p_curr;

        // find separator
        p_next = strpbrk (p_next, sep);

        // strpbrk() returns null pointer if no such character
        // exists in the input string which is part of string pointed by sep
        if (!p_next) {
            p_next = p_curr + strlen (p_curr);
        }

        p_substr[word_cnt] = alloc_str (p_curr, p_next);

        if (p_substr[word_cnt]) {
            word_cnt++;
        }

        p_curr = p_next;
    }

    p_substr[word_cnt] = NULL;
    printf ("Number of words in input string : %u\n", word_cnt);

    for (int i = 0; p_substr[i]; ++i) {
        printf ("%d. %s\n", i + 1, p_substr[i]);
    }
 
    dealloc_str (p_substr);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Number of words in input string : 5
1. Joe
2. James
3. John
4. Maria
5. Micheal
```

If you want to split a string based on multiple separators, e.g. - `" !,"`, then in the above code, just assign `" !,"` to `sep`.